# SOAP Server error in PHP - adding functions from a class

Tags: php, soap

I am writing a SOAP server and have hit a strange problem.

Here's the relevant lines from the server.php

```
class MyHandler {
    public function __construct() { ... }
    public function __wakeup() { ... }

    public function getPrice() { ... }
}

$server = new SoapServer("my.wsdl", array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));

$server->setClass('MyHandler');
$server->addFunction("getPrice");
$server->handle();
```

Testing this locally (on PHP 5.3) works fine and I'm able to send requests and receive responses.

When I put this onto my development server (PHP 5.2.9), I get this error message:

> `SoapServer::addFunction(): Tried to add a non existant function 'getPrice'`

Apart from the fact that they can't spell, this is very confusing.

I've since managed to work around the issue by changing the `addFunction()` line to this:

```
$server->addFunction(SOAP_FUNCTIONS_ALL);
```

... and it works fine! Of course, examining `$server->getFunctions()` shows that this adds the `__construct()` and `__wakeup()` functions from my class too, which doesn't seem like such a good thing.

What did I do wrong? Is the carpet bomb "add all functions" approach the only way here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `addFunction()` tells it to look for a function named `getPrice()` on its own, outside of a class.  This doesn't exist, so is causing the error.

Using `addClass()` will automatically add all the functions from `MyHandler`, so you shouldn't need to call `addFunction()`, `getPrice()` should have already been added.

Additionally, there's an open ticket (for PHP 5.2.9) on bugs.php.net which seems to indicate that there's no way of adding a class method using `addFunction()`: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47919

I don't have access to PHP 5.3 though, so not sure how things may have changed I'm afraid...

Answer (score 2):

`$server->addFunction(array("SOAPMethods", "getPrice"));`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure why it's working on PHP 5.3, but from what I understand, `SoapServer::setClass()` exports all the methods in the given class (ie, your `getPrice()` method will be exported using that).

`SoapServer::addFunction()` works specifically with, well functions. Any chance you had a stray `getPrice()` function lying around in your local environment?

You can test this with commenting out the `addFunction()` call which should still show your exported methods from "MyHandler".

Using **SOAP_FUNCTIONS_ALL** is probably a bad idea, as if you remove the `setClass()` call it actually exports all PHP functions for some reason...

Comment: Nope, I'm quite sure that there's no extra functions being included: there's only one include in the script (including the MyHandler class), and even the contents of that include are pasted into the script, there's no difference.

Comment: Did you try removing the addFunction() call? The setClass() should be sufficient to export all the methods in your class anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP version 5.3.10 and I had the same problem. And I solved it by adding `array` keyword.

Before:

```
 $server->addFunction("functionName");
```

After:

```
 $server->addFunction(array("functionName"));
```

Reference: PHP [SoapServer::addFunction documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.addfunction.php).