# PHP SOAP: Is "SOAP_FUNCTIONS_ALL" safe for SoapServers created in WSDL mode?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234941/1337498) about PHP's `SoapServer::addFunction()` method, there's this remark:

> Using SOAP_FUNCTIONS_ALL is probably a bad idea, as ... it actually exports all PHP functions

And this caution is repeated elsewhere on teh Intertubes, for example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.addfunction.php#78777) and [here](http://www.fantabooks.net/lib/O'Reilly%20-%20PHP%20Cookbook%202nd%20Edition%20Aug%202006/0596101015/phpckbk-CHP-15-SECT-2.php#IDX-CH-15-046).

I've verified experimentally that this is true: in a modest-sized application, `SoapServer::getFunctions()` returns an array of nearly 3,000 functions, starting with `zend_version`, after such a call to `SoapServer::addFunction()`.

However, I'm less able to determine whether this is a problem if the SOAP server is working in WSDL mode (i.e., has been created with a non-null argument specifying a `.wsdl` file to its constructor).

While it's true that I haven't yet found a way to access the ~2,800 functions **not** named in the application's `.wsdl` file, this may be more a matter of my SOAP-Fu being weak than it is evidence that those functions really aren't accessible to a competent attacker.

Is this something to be concerned about as long as no `SoapServer` is created in non-WSDL mode?